# Show used Database in asp.net/c# application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We use several machines and databases to develop a asp.net/c# application.
These are activated or deactivated in appsettings.json respectively.

```
"ConnectionStrings": 
{

// Webserver
//"DefaultConnection": "Server=WEBSRV-2019\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=real_app;user id=sa;password=xxxxxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
//"DefaultConnection": "Server=WEBSRV-2019\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=test1;user id=sa;password=xxxxxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
//"DefaultConnection": "Server=WEBSRV-2019\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=test2;user id=sa;password=xxxxxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"

// HP-WS10
"DefaultConnection": "Server=HP-WS10\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=real_app;user id=sa;password=xxxxxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
//"DefaultConnection": "Server=HP-WS10\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=test1;user id=sa;password=xxxxxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
//"DefaultConnection": "Server=HP-WS10\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=test2;user id=sa;password=xxxxxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
}
```

In this example we use Server "HP-WS10" with database "real_app".

It would be nice to see in the application which database is in use.
To show the user if he works with a development environment or the real application.

My problem is that I don´t know where, and how, to read my "ConnectionStrings" in the application.

Comment: Okay - so what's preventing you from doing that? Have you obtained the connection string in your code? Extracted the database name from it? Passed it to the view? It's not clear which part of this you're stuck on.

Comment: I suppose that you read somewhere the connectionstring. Then you could use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class to pass your current connection string and the get the information you need from the Database property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class to parse and extract connection string information.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

For example:

```
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(myConnectionString);
    
    model.DatabaseServer = builder.DataSource;

    return View(model);
```

Comment: @mason Updated answer for ASP.NET MVC